# Como formatar os dados extraídos do datagridview para o excel

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, datagridview

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
        app.Visible = true;
        worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Plan1"];
        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
        for (int i = 1; i < dGVPosicaoEstoque.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dGVPosicaoEstoque.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dGVPosicaoEstoque.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dGVPosicaoEstoque.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dGVPosicaoEstoque.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dGVPosicaoEstoque.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Preciso formatar os dados que estão sendo extraídos para o excel pois o mesmo não esta diferenciando (.)ponto de (,)virgula. Exemplo: O valor extraido esta desta forma (109.390.759) sendo que o correto seria (109.390,759).

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você quer converter um valor da lista **dGVPosicaoEstoque** no formato 109.390,759.

Supondo que este valor seja um double e esteja cadastrado como **109390.759**. Neste caso você poderá utilizar o método **String.Format** (documentação [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)) para formatá-lo da forma que quiser antes de inseri-lo na planilha.

Veja um exemplo:

```
double valor = 109390.759;

string valorFormatado = string.Format("{0:0,0.000}", valor);

Console.WriteLine(valorFormatado);    // valor impresso: 109.390,759
```